# node-gyp windows 7 Enterprise reactjs/flux

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, reactjs, node-gyp

So my issues are mostly the same as posts from [here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/629). It starts to explain all the issues and steps needed for windows users and node-gyp problems.

As I am sure you can imagine, I ran into the same problems as everyone else on windows trying to run 'npm install'. The culprit is node-gyp. I followed [ToTallNate's](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/wiki/Visual-Studio-2010-Setup) solution step by step multiple times and still can't get node-gyp to do a rebuild. I have uninstalled and reinstalled everything in the correct order only God know's how many times.  My Python is the correct V and is in my PATH as well as node. I've tried on VS2010 and 2015 express with no luck. I am preparing to restore my image to day one and start over again with the installs (it's a new desktop we just started working on so no big losses here)

To give you a quick background My client handed me a stack of Reactjs components that were developed on os x and linux and is pretty much forcing me to use this stack on a windows environment because it uses a tech stack approved for use by this company. The dev team I am working with is all on windows 7 enterprise

My questions are:

1. How many npm modules/packages depend on node-gyp? And just what is node-gyp doing for them? can someone please elaborate/point me in the right direction. I've seen the npm documentation a million times so that won't help me right now...
2. Is there a better set of modules I should be using with windows from npm?
3. Can anyone recommend a better way to get started with a reactjs/flux project on windows? Would grunt work better than gulp?

I'm relatively new to working with this frontend stack so thank you for your patience.

Here is the package.json they want me to work with:

```
`"config": {
    "server_port": "4040",
    "browser_sync_port": "8080",
    "livereload_port": "35729"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp",
    "build": "gulp build --prod",
    "test": "./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js",
    "ci-test": "./scripts/ci-test.sh"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "aliasify": "^1.4.0",
    "async": "^0.9.0",
    "axios": "^0.5.4",
    "body-parser": "^1.9.2",
    "browser-sync": "^1.3.7",
    "browserify": "5.10.0",
    "chai": "^1.9.1",
    "component-mocker": "^0.2.0",
    "compression": "^1.0.11",
    "connect-livereload": "0.4.0",
    "envify": "~3.0.0",
    "express": "~4.8.5",
    "falafel": "^0.3.1",
    "glob": "^4.0.5",
    "gulp": "~3.8.7",
    "gulp-arialinter": "0.0.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.4.3",
    "gulp-if": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-jshint": "~1.8.4",
    "gulp-livereload": "2.1.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-notify": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-react": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-scss-lint": "^0.1.4",
    "gulp-shell": "~0.2.9",
    "gulp-streamify": "0.0.5",
    "gulp-strip-line": "0.0.1",
    "gulp-tar": "^1.3.2",
    "gulp-template": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "~0.3.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-watch": "~0.6.9",
    "jshint-stylish": "~0.4.0",
    "karma": "^0.12.21",
    "karma-bro": "^0.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.2.6",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.3",
    "karma-mocha": "^0.1.9",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "^0.1.1",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.13",
    "merge-stream": "~0.1.5",
    "messageformat": "~0.2.1",
    "mkdirp": "~0.5.0",
    "mocha": "^1.21.4",
    "nopt": "^3.0.1",
    "react-tools": "^0.12.0",
    "reactify": "^0.15.2",
    "request": "^2.47.0",
    "requirefrom": "~0.2.0",
    "rewireify": "~0.0.9",
    "rimraf": "~2.2.8",
    "run-sequence": "~0.3.6",
    "sinon": "^1.10.3",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.5.0",
    "s-ui-build": "0.1.14",
    "s-ui-icon": "^0.1.9",
    "through": "~2.3.4",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^0.1.1",
    "watchify": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "accounting": "^0.4.1",
    "classnames": "^1.1.4",
    "console-shim": "^1.0.3",
    "es5-shim": "^4.0.1",
    "inherits": "^2.0.1",
    "jquery": "~1.11.1",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "moment": "2.7.0",
    "react": "~0.12.0",
    "react-router": "~0.11.6",
    "uuid": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "aliasify": {
    "aliases": {}
  }
}
`
```

Comment: *TooTallNate, apologies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get node-gyp to work on Windows 7 platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200655/how-do-i-get-node-gyp-to-work-on-windows-7-platform)